# On safari browser, input control fetching details from cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, safari

I have a input control

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="User name.."
                                   value=""
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   ng-model="search.FullName">
```

This control is working on chrome properly while on safari it is fetching email from login screen. 
How could I restrict it?

Also this happen in specific system (mac). I also unable to reproduce it on another machine.

Comment: I don't really understand your question but there is no need use the "value" attribute since data will be bound to search.FullName via ng-model.

Comment: Yes you are correct! But I add it to clear cookies value if fetch. Still it not work.

Comment: I'm confused about the fetching and cookie.  I think what you are asking is related to autocomplete.  If so, add the autocomplete="off" attribute to your form tag.

Comment: As you can see, I already add autocomplete="off".

Comment: Did you try googling something like "autocomplete not working safari"?  I did.  Brought up all sorts of solutions.

Comment: My problem is exact opposite. I don't want to autocomplete this